# web scraping : iterate through every page of web app using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm a complete beginner in `javascript` and `puppeteer` and I am trying to get the first 151 pokemon descriptions  from the bulbapedia website `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generation_I_Pok%C3%A9mon`
In the picture below I copy the XPath of the blue marked element of a single pokemon instance and it is the text I want to show

[image]

Using my code below I can succeed in grabbing the element and showing the text in a `json` value but I can only do it manually for one pokemon at a time . What I want is to use `puppeteer` to iterate through each page and do this for the first 151 pokemon
My code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getDesc(url){

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    //xpath of the selected text above in the pic 
    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[5]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td');
    const text = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    srcTxt = await text.jsonValue();

    console.log({srcTxt});

    browser.close();

}



//give url for a specific pokemon as input 
getDesc('https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)');
```

I believe that  a for loop that iterates through each url for every pokemon instance is the solution . However I do not know how to implement this using puppeteer and I would appreciate your help . Thank you in advance .

Comment: I’ve done this in a library available on npm, but you would probably need to get each anchor/link on each visited page, store those links making sure not to duplicate and tracking which ones have been visited already, navigate to page(s)/links recursively and execute the logic you need until you run out of links.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thank you for your response . Is there a better way ?

Comment: What do you mean by better way? If you are asking if puppeteer has a built in method to scrape automatically and recursively whole doing the custom logic you are attempting, it does not. You need to create logic to determine which pages it should visit then execute the visit and logic for each one. But someone may have found a more effective way.

Comment: You can try to search for more automated libraries in these repositories: https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/awesome-puppeteer, https://github.com/lorien/awesome-web-scraping, and https://github.com/simon987/awesome-datahoarding

Comment: hey @VasilisSkentos did you managed to find solution for your puppeteer script (automatic looping on all pages?) I'll take look today and send you - I had similar script recently

Comment: @KresimirPendic I used the FETCH API to get them instead . I took a completly different approach .

Answer (score 2):

If you have a URL array, you can try something like this:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    const urls = ['https://example.org/1', 'https://example.org/2'];
    const allData = [];

    for (const url of urls) {
      await page.goto(url);

      const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('a').innerText;
      });

      allData.push(data);
    }

    console.log(allData);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response . However there could be many 'a' in one page and I want to get a specific 'a'  so how can   const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('a').innerText;
      });  work ? Maybe there is something I don't understand here

Comment: It is just a placeholder. You can scrape any elements and build any complicated data inside the `page.evaluate()` to return it to the puppeteer context and collect.

Comment: But I still have to scrape every element manually right ? This is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: Well, puppeteer is just a facilitator for DevTools protocol interaction between Node.js and browser worlds. You need to implement all the logic with it by yourself. Maybe there are some libraries with more abstractions (like give a list of URLs and selectors and get a list of texts etc.), but I do not know any, sorry.